# Is it possible to design native iOS user interface with the CSS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, css, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I'm interested in such a thing - are there some tools, libraries, etc which will allow to design native iOS UI (UILabels margins, etc.) with the help of CSS? I am not talking about libraries such as `PhoneGap` or `Appcelator`. I'm interested in something like CSS parser which will allow me to transform CSS code into Objective-C UI code or Interface Builder.xib files. Let's say I have a good web-designer fluent in CSS and HTML and I want him to write UI code for my iOS application in CSS+HTML and then I transform it in Objective-C UI code or IB .xib files.

I think my question is clear and I hope for some good answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Services that allow you to design "native apps" or, more accurately, "hybrid apps" are actually bare bones app dominated by a web view or frame for a webpage so that you provide content and styling on a website that is being displayed by the app.  It expands the capabilities of the "app" and allows you to put an app in the store but it is not on a par with true native apps.

There is no elegant conversion from HTML to Objective-C.

Seriously, if you want a native app, make an actual native app.  Otherwise, just stick with a web app.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.nativecss.com/docs/tutorials/intro/ios

for native ios development,it is very good tutorial for ios+CSS

Answer (score 1):

Also check out: http://www.pixate.com/

It's not free but let's you do exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for `PhoneGap`, `AppCelator` etc. to exist is the reason that HTML+CSS (in other words "web pages") cannot be converted into Objective-C easily.

I suggest you take the straightforward way. Teach your designer to use the Interface Builder. It's just a WYSIWYG editor, nothing complicated even for a designer.

Comment: @BenClayton It wasn't meant to be offensive. The problem with people is that sometimes they don't want to learn new things (new tools) or even fear them ("I am not a programmer, I don't want to use XCode"). Actually, my product manager, my designer and testers can all use git and install the latest version of apps to their device with XCode. All the designers are able to use the Interface Builder. However, they don't create the xibs, they just check which components, fonts, settings are available.